# Read SMS using Java in old style phones

Tags: java, java-me, sms

I have a installable application in J2Me/Java, developed for old style (Non Android or Smartphone) phones.

We have registration process which sends a SMS with various parameters to longcode which in return sends back license key through SMS to same number. Now this license key we need to read from SMS and store in phones memory.

I absolutely have no idea where to start, found some information about AT commands but thats for Modem or Port based external applications.

Any clue would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Basically all there is to know, is that you can't read the standard inbox with JavaME. But you can receive incoming SMS on any non-standard port. Meaning any other port. So you just have to send the SMS on some defined port, e.g. 50000, and then code your JavaME function to listen for SMS on port 50000.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your phone supports Wireless Messaging API

Here's the official javadocs (contains some code example at the end of page) http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Java/_zip/GUID-71D2FC38-3A7C-4F69-9A2C-C307ABF33D6C/overview-summary.html

For more low-level detail, you can refer to this article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/wma2-137168.html